# Output objects from within a for loop in R, with name changes in each step

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a for loop that outputs a specific sql query, based on criteria that change with each step.  Further, I'm trying to designate the output names based on the step that create them.  For example, step 1 would output a table called species1.  The code as I've tried to write it is below.  I'm sure the answer is simple, but for the life of me I can't figure out the right way to phrase this.  Thanks in advance for all your help

```
for (i in 1:15) {
Species[i]<-sqldf("SELECT StartYear, StartMonthNo, RegionCode, CommonName, EstimatedBiomassg, ScaledProportionofDominantNektonBiomass
                FROM TrawlBiomassbyMonth
                WHERE CommonName = TopSpecies[i,1]
                AND RegionCode=1")

Species[i]TimeSeries<-sqldf("SELECT TimeSeries.StartYear, TimeSeries.StartMonthNo, CommonName, EstimatedBiomassg, ScaledProportionofDominantNektonBiomass
                FROM TimeSeries
                LEFT JOIN Species[i]
                ON TimeSeries.StartYear = Species1.StartYear 
                AND TimeSeries.StartMonthNo = Species1.StartMonthNo")
Species[i]TimeSeries[is.na(Species[i]TimeSeries)] <- 0}
```

EDIT

Here is a simplified example:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  Species[i]<-sqldf("SELECT StartYear, StartMonthNo, CommonName, Biomass
                    FROM ExampleBiomass
                    WHERE CommonName = ExampleTopSpecies[i,1])}
```

dput of biomass

```
structure(list(StartYear = c(1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 
1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1986L, 1986L, 
1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 
1986L), StartMonthNo = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L), CommonName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Ninja", "Pirate"), class = "factor"), Biomass = c(26L, 
107L, 126L, 35L, 84L, 147L, 98L, 141L, 112L, 43L, 28L, 79L, 36L, 
126L, 31L, 89L, 133L, 34L, 38L, 117L, 92L, 81L, 93L, 127L)), .Names = c("StartYear", 
"StartMonthNo", "CommonName", "Biomass"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

dput of TopSpecies

```
structure(list(CommonName = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Ninja", 
"Pirate"), class = "factor"), Biomass = c(500L, 450L)), .Names = c("CommonName", 
"Biomass"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: You should probably use a list to store the output instead of creating objects with the names you specified.  It's much cleaner and a lot easier to do programmatically.  It also sounds like you should take a look at `paste`.

Comment: Create a simple reproducible example and show the input and output. Use `dput` to make it easy to reproduce the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
basic_query <- "SELECT StartYear, StartMonthNo, CommonName, Biomass FROM ExampleBiomass WHERE CommonName = "

Species <- list()

for (i in 1:2) {
  Species[[i]] <- sqldf(paste(basic_query, as.character(ExampleTopSpecies[i,1])))
}
```

Some explanation:

- `basic_query` saves the commom part of the SQL queries.
- `Species <- list()` creates an empty list object that will be filled by your loop.
- `Species[[i]] <-` adds an element to list `Species`.
- `paste` simply concatenates strings.
- `as.character(ExampleTopSpecies[i,1])` is needed because your dataframes contain factors.